# Python after starting a program on command line I can't turn to my code

Tags: python, python-2.7, vnc

I created a loop which is allowing me to connect IP addresses via VNC which are in a list. We are operating a small bussiness and we wanted to start/connect all of our servers with one program. After the first connection it stucks in vncviewer and it does not continuing with other IPs. Only after I close the VNC connection, it continues with the other IP address, and again it stucks in the vncviewer.

I type on command line "python connectvnc.py" and it gives me normally
"192.168.1.15 starting VNC Viewer..." then it starts the connection and it stucks right there. Program stops to contiue with other IP addresses until I close opened connection.

```
#python 2.7.7
def vncviewer():
        print (i + " starting VNC Viewer...")
        os.system("vncviewer.exe " + str(i) + "::5900 -password password")
l=[]
with open("Servers.txt", "r") as file: #in here I export them in a list
        for x in file:
        l.append(x[:-1])
for i in l:
        vncviewer()
```

I only want you to fix the problem that I mentioned. I tried to add "pass" but it did not work either. How can I make my code not to stuck after starting exe file ?

Comment: It sounds like an issue with `vncviewer.exe` hanging downstream.  Is your `vncviewer.exe` program running when the Python script hangs?  Is it properly exiting?

Comment: yes it does, actually i just press the cancel button but it works properly. When the RealVNC's vncviewer.exe closes it continues.

Comment: isn't there any code blocks which allows to return to the code ? I mean I thought that if I wrote pass it would continue with other IP addresses and the previous vncviewer would be OK.

Comment: Python is synchronous-by-default. `os.system()` is a synchronous method, it will halt the rest of the script until `vncviewer.exe` has completed execution.
You will may need to refactor your script to use [asynchronous subprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#examples) to fix your issue.